# Using pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn() in Windows to run a telnet instance

Tags: python, linux, windows

Has anyone had luck running pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn() to run telnet in Windows?

Note that I've already enabled the "Telnet Client" feature from Windows as I'm able to run "telnet" from the command line fine by simply typing 'telnet' in the command line.

```
import sys
import pexpect

from pexpect.popen_spawn import PopenSpawn

EXPECTED_PROMPT = "> "

def test():
    telnet_port=4444

    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        telnet = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn(
            "C:\Windows\System32\telnet localhost {}".format(telnet_port),
            timeout=120,
            logfile=sys.stdout)
        telnet.expect(EXPECTED_PROMPT)

    return telnet

if __name__ == "__main__":
    telnet = test()
```

When I try running the code above I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 26, in <module>
  telnet = test()
File ".\test.py", line 20, in test
  logfile=sys.stdout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\popen_spawn.py", line 53, in 
__init__
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: `"C:\Windows\System32\telnet localhost {}"` isn't a raw string, so `"\t"` is a tab character, which is certainly not what you want, and it's also an invalid filename character in Microsoft's file systems (but not all Windows file systems, such as a VirtualBox shared folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around the problem by using plink: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

Instead of

```
C:\Windows\System32\telnet localhost {}
```

I used

```
plink.exe -telnet localhost -P {}
```